# Multiples Queries inside Loop not all work

Tags: php, loops

I try to optimize a script I have so that it loads faster.
Now I have been sitting here for hours already but do not get it to work correctly.

The first part works fine, but what does not work is getting the names of the sire_id ($sr query) and dam_id (($ dr query)
it shows as resuls "array" for all of them.

This is what I have written so far

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(sire_id) as c, sire_id FROM dog WHERE sire_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY sire_id ORDER BY c desc LIMIT 150"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) ;
$i=0;
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $sireQuery = "SELECT name, id, sire_id, dam_id FROM dog WHERE id = '$line[sire_id] '";
    $sireResult = mysql_query($sireQuery) ;
    $sireLine = mysql_fetch_array($sireResult);
    $sr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id like $sireLine[2]") ;
    $sl = mysql_fetch_array($sr);       
    $dr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id like $sireLine[3]") ;
    $dl = mysql_fetch_array($sr);                       
    $i++;

    echo "</td><td>".$i. '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;',"<a href='details.php?id=".$line[1]."'>"  .$sireLine[0]. "</td>
          <td>".$line[0]." </td>
          <td>".$sl." </td>
          <td>".$dl." </td></tr>";      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ids are numeric by definition, you don't need to use quotes. Also, you added a space that is not necessary:

```
$sireQuery = "SELECT name, id, sire_id, dam_id FROM dog WHERE id = " . $line["sire_id"];
```

Also, the following lines may need adaptation (waiting for your answer about the datatype of the id column)

```
$sr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id = " . $sireLine["sire_id"]);
$sl = mysql_fetch_array($sr);
$dr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id = " . $sireLine["dam_id"]);
$dl = mysql_fetch_array($dr);   /* note the mistake in the variable name: this is $dr, not $sr */
```

...

```
<td>" . $sl["name"] ." </td>
<td>" . $dl["name"] ." </td></tr>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that part of my script does work, I tried it with changing it to your part of the code but still than the $sr and $dr are not working:
http://prntscr.com/1aairs

Comment: please tell if the ids are actually numbers or strings

Comment: They are actual numbers.

If a dog gets added in the database they get an unique ID

Comment: Ok, so the LIKE is not necessary either. Try the code I added and tell me the results

Comment: Well that is a dumb thing from me I already wondered why it only said "array" under sire and nothing under dam. Well now at least I see that under both. 
But this way with a little change in the coding the loading is a lot faster! What a difference that makes, it still does not work though

http://prntscr.com/1aamey

Comment: This is because you didn't use any column definer in the sl and dl arrays. See my update

Answer (score 0):

I rewrited your example:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(sire_id) as c, sire_id FROM dog WHERE sire_id IS NOT NULL GROUP BY sire_id ORDER BY c desc LIMIT 150";
$result = mysql_query($query) ;
$i=0;

while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $sireQuery = "SELECT name, id, sire_id, dam_id FROM dog WHERE id = {$line['sire_id']}";
    $sireResult = mysql_query($sireQuery) ;
    $sireLine = mysql_fetch_assoc($sireResult);
    $sr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id = {$sireLine['sire_id']}") ;
    $sl = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr);
    $dr = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM dog WHERE id = {$sireLine['sire_id']}") ;
    $dl = mysql_fetch_assoc($sr);
    $i++;

    echo "</td><td>".$i. '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;',"<a href='details.php?id=".$line[1]."'>"  .$sireLine[0]. "</td>
          <td>{$line['c']} </td>
          <td>{$sl['name']} </td>
          <td>{$dl['name']} </td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had to make a few adjustments, but it is working now. And yet again I learned something.
And besides that it is working a lot faster which was my whole reason to rewrite the script I had!

Comment: Glad it helped. Mark question answered ;)